# Rails & JS: Make panels generated by .each function toggle independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble having only on dropdown dropdown at a time. The problem is that I am using a .each fucntion. Therfore I do not know how to make it so that each dropdown has a specific id or class in order to make my `.click` function run seperatly on each dropdown.

This is my embedded ruby file:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading show_hide_panel"></div>
  <div class="panel-body panel">
   ....
  </div>
</div>
<%end%>
```

This is what I have as JS:

```
$(".panel").hide();

$(".show_hide_panel").click(function(){
  $(".panel").slideToggle();
});
```

**My Question:** How can I make it so each panel, which will be generated by the.each, toggle on click independently and not all at once when only one is clicked.

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: you should use an id instead of a class. maybe use the index in the iteration as an id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery has a way of doing this. Basically you can get the element you clicked on by using `$(this)` within the function.

In your particular case, you're clicking on the `panel-header` so it becomes `$(this)` in the function. You want to open the `panel-body`, so you select its sibling  `$(this).siblings('.panel-body').slideToggle()`.
 Complete code:

```
$(document).on("click",".panel-heading", function () {

         $(this).siblings('.panel-body').slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Problem with "this" is that I am not toggling this but an item inside "this". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try with $(this).children( ".panel-body" ).slideToggle(); or whatever the identifier is the of the item inside.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Since panel-body isn't a children of the heading.

Comment: $(document).on("click",".panel-primary", function () {}); should work. Or , better yet, console.log( $(this) ) to see what you're actually clicking and let me know.

Comment: If it is the panel-heading you can replace .children('.panel-body') with .siblings('.panel-body')

Comment: I've updated my answer. Can you mark it as 'solved', please?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".show_hide_panel").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".panel-primary").find(".panel-body").slideToggle();
});
```